# Contact us email not sending

Tags: magento-1.7, email, magento-community, forms, contact-form

I am working in localhost with Magento 1.7. When I fill the form under the contact us page (`myurl/contacts/`), I don't receive any email at all.

I have checked `Admin -> System -> Genera -> Conctacts`, and I have the option enabled, and the email set to my email account. I tried 'Custom Email 1' and 'Custom Email 2'. Still, I receive no email when I fill and send the contacts form.

I already tried to change `$this->getFormAction();` and use `getUrl()` as suggested in other posts, but I obtained no result.

Whenever I create a new user, for example, I receive an email, so I guess that the problem is not sending emails but there must be another problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Do you get success message after form submit? Also check your log files for errors if any.

Comment: I don't get success message. I checked log and saw no errors.

Comment: If there is no success message then you need to debug your contacts controller post action code where it is breaking.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this, Hope It's helpful for you.**

> your website is just on localhost, which does not support sending email (some tools allow but not many).
>
> The following solution will help you much with email problem of Magento on localhost, which enables you debug and test email.
>
> Link to download: https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension
>   (Download Magento SMTP Pro Extension by Ashley Schroder (free)
>
> For More details,kindly visit below URLs:-
>
> http://www.mage-world.com/blog/how-to-set-up-sending-emails-on-localhost-for-magento.html

Comment: Thank you. I already saw this but didn't try because whenever I create a new user an email is sent, so I assume localhost is capable of sending emails. I am using WAMP. I got exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()' in C:\wamp64\www\magento\lib\Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail.php:137

Comment: Any other suggestion? This didn't work for me :\

Comment: @LeCodeur You can not send mail from localhost i mean on WAMP server...magento doesn't support mail functionality on localhot.

Comment: Please try my below My Anser @LeCodeur https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191579/18639

Comment: I agree but if make some changes, please see below my new answer .. then you can send mail to magento @Dhrumin

Answer (score 0):

> You are using wrong SMTP settings for gmail. The correct ones are:

**In php.ini**

```
[mail function]
;SMTP = localhost
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
sendmail_path = "c:\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

**In sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
auth_username=me@example.com
auth_password=**********
```

**Remeber:**

> If you have enabled [2 step authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en), you have to create an
>   application specific password.